# Flutter Android build fail after project upgrade from Flutter 3.0.5 to 3.3.10

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am getting this issue after flutter upgrade to latest stable on 1st Feb 2022, its been a year I have not upgraded my flutter project yet, and I wanna add new packages which requires the latest android compile version 33 so I have upgrade both flutter and dart to match the new dependeies

Steps I followed to upgrade my project

1. flutter channel stable
2. flutter upgrade
3. flutter doctor
4. flutter pub outdated
5. flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
6. flutter pub cache repair
7. flutter clean && flutter pub get
8. flutter build apk

At this point, I knew I have done all the important steps required to upgrade my flutter project but there was something missing that caused so many issues.

````
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewTreeViewModelKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1)
Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.```
````

Answer (score 0):

So first thing I upgraded my dart SDK version in project pubspec.yaml file

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.1 <3.0.0'
```

to

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.0 <3.0.0'
```

then I updated my kotlin version in android/build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
```

to

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
```

Some gradle dependencies in the same file

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.2.301'
    }
```

to

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.5.2.300'
    }
```

Now the main changes in the android/app/build.gradle file
I have updated the android compile and target SDK versions they should be same as per my knowledge and added a lifecycle view model dependency in the project to fix this issue

```
android {
 compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "YOUR_BUNDLE_ID"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
```

Comment: I added this question and solution to stack overflow because I spent two days just to fix this issue.